# Is there a short way to check array size before going into for loop?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am using it like this:

```
if json.count>0{
   for i in 0...json.count-1{

   }
}
```

Is there a better and shorter way to safely start a for loop ?

Comment: @Bhavin it's not a dupe of that question.

Comment: Why you need to check size ? if array is nil then for loop will not execute

Comment: @Bhavin Well, OK, the question is different but the answer is the same. I wouldn't bother to vote for reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the initial condition:

```
for i in 0..<json.count {
    // Do something
}
```

If the range in the loop is impossible the code will not get executed.

Also, if you don't use `i` inside the brackets you can replace it with `_`.

Comment: Hmm I didnt know you could do that in for loop. I always assumed its 3 dots no matter what. Can you point me to some documentation on what is possible with the dots there?

Comment: @JacobSmith The `..<` is the half open range operator, whereas the `...` is the closed range operator. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID73

Comment: Yup.  That was my way of making it even shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fragment is identical to

```
for i in 0 ..< json.count { ... }
```

There's no penalty for executing a loop zero times.

Even better

```
for element in json { /* do stuff with element */ }
```

Or if you *need* the index:

```
for (i, element) in json.enumerate() { }
```